# Joomla 2.5 site task will not fire

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-task

Here is my issue. I have a form that I want to send data to a JSON task. However no matter what I do the task will not run. I just get the following error:

`Invalid controller: name='controls', format='json'`

As far as I can see there is nothing that should prevent the controller from running. Here is the code.

```
class HelloWorldControllerControls extends JController{
    /*function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }*/
    public function postal(){
        JFactory::getDocument()->setMimeEncoding( 'application/json' );
        JResponse::setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename="status.json"');
        //$postal = JRequest::getVar('postal_code',false);
        //$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
        //$saveLocalCookie = $dispatcher->trigger('onSavePostalCode', array('code'=>$postal));
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
        jexit();
    }
}
```

This is of course in the site `controllers` folder and named `controls.json.php`

I have matched this with another controller I am using in the admin panel that does pretty much the exact same thing, but it works in admin, not in the site.

The JRoute I am using to try to call this is.

`index.php?option=com_helloworld&task=controls.postal&format=json`

Anything I may be overlooking?

EDIT:

To clarify, I need to call the task directly, as all I will be doing is outputting raw data in JSON format, there is no need for a view, only a model an controller. Currently since I am still in testing there is no need for the model yet.

EDIT 2:

Found part of an answer, but am going to leave it open as this answer is not really that great. Its impossible based on how Joomla sets up MVC in the "site" portion (based on my tests). It always looks for view first, then controller. I could only get the task to fire by making sure a view was set. There is a chance I am wrong and misled from my tests because an open source framework not building MVC correctly seems illogical.

So in order to fix this you need to use a "view" as a "controller".

Comment: This may be of help http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2282503

Comment: Seen that however does not seem to be the same issue. I will update question to clarify, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, but I doubt I could be of any further help, thought I would see what I could find on Google for you. Good luck Jordan, cheers.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, so I would suggest you try calling your task directly from the browser, and you could use firebug's network feature to verify what you're sending and what you're getting back. It looks like it's not finding your controller. Valentin Despa is right, you could use raw instead of json, and there's no need to set the headers if you handle things accordingly (like specifing the response format in jquery).

Answer (score 0):

The controller file name should be `controls.php`

OR

maybe if the output is raw, name it `controls.raw.php` and  add `&format=raw` at the end.

Comment: Tried to remove the .json portion, have not tried .raw yet though. WSIR - no luck with either, same erro with no change.

Comment: `Invalid controller: name='controls', format='raw'` same thing slightly different error.

Comment: Will it work if you call it `controls.php` and leave off the format key entirely? I can see why you would want to specify the format, but I don't think it is actually necessary.

Comment: @DavidFritsch: If you don't specify the format, it will look for the "regular" view. I know it doesn't if you use the raw format as Valentin has pointed out. In this way one can directly output from a controller.

Comment: I have tried every naming structure the internet has given me on Joomla, even some it has not. I have updated my question with the way I ended up fixing it, not a real solution but I feel if more people can recreate this it should be marked as something for the folks at Joomla to look into (that is if I am not just completely missing something)

Comment: That's very odd. I do this all the time. I have lots of components that just have a controller with no associated model or view of the same name. I load them using the same `task` setup. Since the controller ends with a `jexit()` It should not ever look for the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide whether to use the new mvc o the old. The new is much better for REST.

IF you extend JController as opposed to JControllerLegacy you are using the new MVC. YOu should use the REST routing and other things that go with that.

In new MVC there is a one task per controller design.  e.g. Display (Get), Create (Post), Update, Delete and then you may need additional ones.

Postal does not make sense as a task since it is not a verb.

Comment: "postal" was just a shorter version of "postal code" as the task is built to log a users postal code in a cookie/session. But I am confused, do you mean use legacy instead?

Comment: You look like you are using the legacy MVC so you should say
extends JControllerLegacy nto JController ... see all the extensions in the core CMS for examples of this.

Comment: @Elin: He says he's using Joomla 2.5, so there's no new MVC and hence no need to add the legacy suffix, am I correct?